# Handling re-authentication with RxSwift and Moya

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have a project where I'm using Moya with RxSwift extensions.
The simple use cases work fine, I'm able to do requests and get responses in the form of Observables.

```
public func test() -> Observable<Response> {
    return provider
    .request(.test)
    .retry(5)
}
```

I can then subscribe to the observable and print the response with no problem.

But now I need to handle authentication logic. The way it works is that I run the above request with a token added as an HTTP Header Field. Moya allows me to that transparently by using *endpointByAddingHTTPHeaderFields* in the endpointClosure. No problem so far.

The problem arises when the request fails with HTTP status 401, that means I need to re-authenticate by calling another endpoint

```
provider.request(.auth(user, pass)).retry(5)
```

This returns another Observable that I can easily map to JSON to get the new token.

I then just have to call *test()* again!

**So my question is...** How can I add this authentication logic inside the *test()* function above, so that the Observable returned by *test()* is already guaranteed to have run the re-authentication logic in case of failure and be the result of a second re-authenticated request.

I'm very new to RXSwift and RX in general, so I'm a bit clueless about the operators I would use to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Does the 401 come through as an error, or is it a valid response object?

Comment: If the former, this answer might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841054/rxswift-user-input-on-error-and-continuation/38341690#38341690

Answer (score -1):

```
public func test(with authToken: String) -> Observable<Response> {
    return provider
      .request(.test)
      .endpointByAddingHTTPHeaderFields(["Authorization": authToken])
      .catchError { error in
        if needsReauth(error) {
          return provider.request(.auth(user, pass)).map { parseToken($0) }
            .flatMap { token in
              return test(with: token)
            }
        } else {
          return .error(error)
        }
      }
}
```

[`catchError`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/catch.html) enables to continue observable's execution using another observable. The observable we define here does the following:

1. First, it will request the `.auth` endpoint.
2. It then reads from the response to get the new auth token
3. Finally, we recursively call `test(with authToken: String)` to retry querying the test enpoint.